# Why is the advantage in a class variable referencing to an object? instead of storing the object itself

Tags: java, object, reference, class-variables

I was wondering what would be the advantage of a class variable storing a reference to an object rather than storing the object directly in its memory location?

Does it have to do with memory issues or is it a security issue.

I tried looking around, i could not find this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java stores Object in heap memory but from code we need to access that Object using some handle, and so is the reference

Also while GCing when there is no active reference object is no longer needed and will be GC ready

Comment: What is GCing? I may know it by some other name, if there is one. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its more about memory as while copying or passing object to function you need not create/copy a object you just copy reference.

For Eg:

```
Class1 a = new Class1();
Class1 b = a;
```

If you don't store references then in that case you will need to create another Object for b causing duplicity.

Secondly ,

```
public void(Class1 obj){
  //Some operation to Object
}
```

If you pass whole of Object rather than reference , you will again need memory to hold the copied Object.

Comment: Yeah that definitely makes sense. That would waste a ton of memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't have referencing it would be impossible to implement most data structures. Consider doubly linked lists, or a tree where the nodes contain parent links.